# Eager load and list only specific Blogs Per User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A `User` has_many `blogs`, and a `Blog` belongs_to a `user`. I want to group the `Blogs` by `User` so that I can display/break down the blogs-per-user in the view.

Here's the thing: I do not want to grab **all** of the `blogs` for all the `users`.  I DO want to grab all the `users`, but I only want to grab a couple of `blogs`.

If I did want to grab **all** of the blogs I could simply do this in the controller:

```
    @users = User.includes(:blogs).all #eager loads, grabs ALL of the associated blogs
```

And then in the view: to display them by `user` do this:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <h3><%= user.name + " (#{user.blogs.size} blogs)" %></h3>
  <% if user.blogs.any? %>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Blog Title</th>
        <th>Created At</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <% user.blogs.each do |blog| %>
        <tr>
          <td> <%= link_to(blog, blog)%></td>
          <td> <%= blog.created_at.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")%></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

However, I do not want to eager load/grab/display **all** of the associated `blogs` per `users`.  I only want to grab blogs with `ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Assume that I have an array of the blog ids that I want to grab:

```
blog_ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

According to the rails guides for [Eager Loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations) and [Array conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions), I thought I could do something like this:

```
@all_users_and_only_desired_associated_blogs = User.includes(:blogs).where("blogs.id IN ?", blog_ids).references(:blogs)
```

Basically: I want to pretend that only the `blogs` with those ids exist: so eager load them and ignore any of the other `blogs` whenever I call `user.blogs` for a particular user. I think I am close with that query, but it is erroring out.

The next step is to make sure that when I call `user.blogs` that it is not grabbing ALL of those `users'` associated `blogs`, but only those that were eager loaded from earlier.

Ex in view:

```
<% @all_users_and_only_desired_associated_blogs.each do |user| %>
  <p> <%= user.name %> </p>
  <% user.blogs.each do |blog| %> #only the associated, eager loaded blogs, not ALL of the associated blogs
    <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= blog.title%><p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is the error you got with that query?

Comment: @Pavan `SQLite3::SQLException: near "1": syntax error: SELECT "users"."id" AS t0_r0, "users"."name" AS t0_r1, "users"."created_at" AS t0_r2, "users"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "blogs"."id" AS t1_r0, "blogs"."title" AS t1_r1, "blogs"."user_id" AS t1_r2, "blogs"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "blogs"."updated_at" AS t1_r4 FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "blogs" ON "blogs"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (blogs.id IN 1,2,3,4,5,6)`

Comment: Try `User.includes(:blogs).where("blogs.id IN (?)", blog_ids).references(:blogs)`

Comment: @Pavan so when I call `user.blogs` for a particular user, it will only grab any associated blogs that have an id within that blog_id array?

Comment: @Pavan it works for the most part.  The only thing it doesn't do is it does not grab ALL of the `users`.  Instead, it only grabs those associated `users` to the `blogs` that are grabbed.  Does that make sense?  Any tips on how to definitely grab all the `users`, even if they have no associated `blogs` in that `blog_id` array??

Comment: @Pavan, please provide an answer so that I can give you credit for  your answer/helping me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pavan's suggestion in the comments, here is what worked for me:

```
User.includes(:blogs).where("blogs.id IN (?)", blog_ids).references(:blogs)
```